# File upload with php issue

Tags: php, html, image, file, upload

I'm attempting to get a file upload element working on our web page, so a client can upload pictures to us.
I downloaded a nice looking picture uploading element from code pen

Then I got the PHP code from w3 schools (the complete code is at the bottom):

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

The browser is returning an error on the first check with 'getimagesize'. It says:

Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in W:\xampp\htdocs\image-upload-preview\upload.php on line 10
File is not an image.Sorry, your file was not uploaded.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <h1>Image-upload with preview</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="js--image-preview"></div>
    <div class="upload-options">
      <label>
        <input type="file" class="image-upload" accept="image/*" name="fileToUpload" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>


if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
} else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

}

Comment: Way too little info in your question for us to be able to help you. Please show us your form and PHP processing code.

Comment: And the content you have shown us is not valid php. And you've not done any analysis of the problem.

Comment: The top half is the the HTML, the bottom half is the PHP - both just snippets.
The full php can be found at the W3schools link above.

Answer (score 0):

the warning you are getting is not breaking your code. to fix the warning check if the file you are calling has is set by

```
$checkfile = isset($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']) ? $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'] : '';
```

then

```
$check = getimagesize($checkfile);
```

The problem you are having is the file is empty so it is running your else statement and making $uploadOk = 0. Try to figure out where the image is going and make sure it gets placed in the $_FILES['fileToUpload'] array.

Comment: Thank you for the response :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. I started from scratch with a much better tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaRq73y5MJk)
I also had to contend with the file size limit within the php,ini (then forgot to restart apache), but I eventually got it working. Here's my php code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
//the name 'file' is from the HTML
//$_FILES is a super global
$file = $_FILES['file'];

//creating variables for the file attributes
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
$fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

//creates an array for the name and extension
$fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);

//creates variable for the lower case extension, from the end of the array
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

//allowed extensions
$allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','png','tif');

//checks
if(in_array($fileActualExt,$allowed)){ 
        if($fileError === 0){
            if($fileSize < 25000000){
                //creates a new file name
                $fileNameNew = uniqid('',true).".".$fileActualExt;
                //set file destination
                $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
                //moves from temp to proper destination
                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName,$fileDestination);
                //goes back to previous page upon sucess
                header("Location: index.html?uploadsucsess");
            }else{
                echo "File must be less than 25 mb";
            }
        } else{
            echo "There was an error uploading your file";
            echo $fileError;
        }
    } else{
        echo "Invalid File Type Must be a JPG, PNG, or TIF";
    }
```

}